# how to union record from another table with only different id by "Union All"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with duplicate record including 'Id' field, and I need union them.
But I think [union all] is much more efficient than [union]
for the reason that it need not sorting.

Following is my sql:
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[RealTime]
**UNION ALL**
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Query] a
WHERE *NOT* EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM [dbo].[RealTime] b
    WHERE  **a.Id = b.Id**
  )
  Will you have any suggestion or more elegant statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 (yours): query dbo.RealTime first, then query dbo.Query, then for each row from dbo.Query, do a lookup on dbo.Realtime.

Option 2 (UNION): query dbo.RealTime, query dbo.Query, then remove duplicates.

**Apart from the fact that these two options will give different results** (the first option will retain duplicates obtained from dbo.RealTime and dbo.Query), I'd say Option 2 will most probably be less resource intensive since it doesn't have to query dbo.RealTime twice - unless (perhaps) dbo.RealTime is smaller than dbo.Query by an order of magnitude.

Comment: dbo.RealTime is much smaller than dbo.Query. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your sample sql get recordset without record in the second table whose id is same but maybe other fields are different.
Is it your requirement?